# SQL command to perform COUNT on GROUP BY and attach some extra data?

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I'm not sure how well the subject describes the problem but it's the best I could come up with. I have two tables:

```
Users                  UserNames

UserID | CompanyID     UserID | Name
--------------------   ---------------
   1   |    30            1   | John
   2   |    32            2   | Anne 
   2   |    32            3   | Mark 
   3   |    33            4   | Kris 
   4   |    32            5   |  Tom
```

What I'm trying to create is a summary of users for a particular company. For example, creating the summary for CompanyID 32 would result in:

```
UserID | Name | Count
---------------------
   2   | Anne |   2
   4   |  Tom |   1
```

Using the following SQL query comes close:

```
SELECT UserID, Count(UserID)
FROM Users
WHERE CompanyID = 32
GROUP BY UserID

UserID | Count
---------------------
   2   |   2
   4   |   1
```

But I can't figure out how to add the Name column. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks from a SQL rookie,
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Users.UserID, Count(Users.UserID), UserNames.Name
FROM Users
INNER JOIN UserNames ON UserNames.UserID = Users.UserID
GROUP BY Users.UserID, UserNames.Name
```

Optionally you can then add the following line to only get the users who appear more than once

```
HAVING  Count(Users.UserID) > 1
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast. I was just coming back to post that because naturally I find the answer right after posting the question. I'd much rather give the credit to someone else though, and will as soon as the cooldown timer runs out:)